# JQuery UI selectable widget - impossible to drag down (flick) with touch screen on chrome for mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile, touch

I have a DIV that is set to "Selectable" thanks to a Jquery UI widget (so the user can select the desired item), but in Chrome for mobile, the ability to drag up and down (flick) on the touch screen is disabled only for the selectable area defined above. However it works for other browsers.

Would you know a work around or a way to enable drag for the selectable area?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

The HTML looks like :

```
<div id='selectable'>
   <div><img src="item1.png"><span>Label1</span></div>
   <div><img src="item2.png"><span>Label2</span></div>
   <div><img src="item3.png"><span>Label3</span></div>
   <div><img src="item4.png"><span>Label4</span></div>
   <div><img src="item5.png"><span>Label5</span></div>
   <div><img src="item6.png"><span>Label6</span></div>      
</div>
```

And the Jquery :

```
$(function() {
$("#selectable").selectable({selected: function(event, ui) { 
        //Preventing from multiple selection
        $('.ui-selected').addClass("uiselected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
      //Catch the value and put it in the POST
        var text=$('.ui-selected').text();
        $('input[name="icone"]').val(text);    
   }});
```

});

Comment: It would be helpful to add the appropriate code here so people can better assist you.

Comment: Done ! Code added. Thank a lot for your help !